# Snap a Point to a Polygon Edge in Direction of Connecting Line in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I'm looking to create a model or write some python for this task, but I'm not entirely sure where to start. I have a point that falls within a polygon feature representing building footprints. Instead of the point being in the center I would like it to be snapped to the edge of the building footprint. The position/direction that it snaps would be determined by the direction of the line that it is attached to. Then I would need that line to shorten to maintain the distance between the snapped point and the other endpoint. Essentially going from the first image to the second image. My first stab at a workflow would be to find the intersection xy of the footprint and yellow line, then relocate the green point to that xy coordinate, then trim the yellow line to the length of the xy point. But I'm also thinking there might be a better way to achieve this using some combination of the Snap and Integrate tools. Also, this data is not geometrically networked, so do not have to worry about breaking the network connectivity.

**Before**

[image]

**Goal**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  If you wish to ask about the ModelBuilder of either please include your test model. If you wish to ask about ArcPy please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you confirm if the thick yellow line that links the green point to the blue point actually exists, i.e. it's not something you have drawn to show the problem you want to solve? Is it attributed with the id of yellow point?

Comment: Yes, the yellow line actually exists, and yes, it is attributed with a shared ID that would tabularly connect it to the yellow/green point.

Comment: I'm trying in ArcMap. I can go and add an arcpy code snippet, but as I said, I'm just getting started and wanted to get feedback on the best steps for this approach